# Pthreads and classes

Tags: c++, class, pthreads, posix

I have made a Queue-class containing storage vectors and mutexes.
To initialise the queue, a thread needs to be started. To make sure the thread is started correctly, the constructor waits for a signal. The thread function is a friend of the Queue-class. However, the signal is not registered when sent by the thread function. Why?

```
Queue::Queue()
{
    (...)
    pthread_mutex_init( &mutex_cond_init, NULL);
    Q_ready = false;
    (...)
    pthread_create(&thread_ID, NULL, Queue_function, this);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_cond_init);
    while(!Q_ready)
    {
        cout << "waiting" << endl;
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond_init,&mutex_cond_init);
        cout << "got signal" << endl;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_cond_init);
    cout << "Queue open." <<endl;
}


void * Queue_function (void*arg)
{
    (...)
    Queue * S = (Queue*) arg;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(*S).mutex_cond_init);
     (*S).Q_ready = true;

     pthread_cond_signal(&(*S).cond_init);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(*S).mutex_cond_init);
    (...)
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you initialised `cond_init`? Your code only shows initialisation of `mutex_cond_init`.

Comment: Also, you would benefit greatly from wrapping resources (such as mutexes, and also mutex locks) in exception-safe RAII-style classes that release the resource in their destructors. See, for example, how `boost::mutex`, and `std::mutex` in C++0x, work.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Please post your suggestion to initialize the condition variable as an answer. @pjaall: Please accept Mike's answer once he posts it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initialised `cond_init`? Your code only shows initialisation of `mutex_cond_init`.